# Typescript: T extends string | number = string?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How should one understand the following typescript generic declaration?

It's not clear to me what purpose, additional value, or difference `= string` adds to the type definition

```
const match = <T extends string | number = string>(value: T) => {
    console.log("value", value);
}

match(1) // returns 1
match("hi") // returns hi
match("1") // returns "1"
```

Specifically, what is the difference between these two declarations? To my untrained eye, they both mean `T` can be a number or string

```
T extends string | number
T extends string | number = string
```

Comment: `= string` is the default value. If `T` is unspecified, it defaults to `string`.

Comment: Oh... right. Makes sense. You can post a reply and I'll accept it as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`= string` is the default value. If `T` is unspecified, it defaults to `string`

In the examples where you showed it being used, typescript can infer what T is from the way it's being used, so for example, `match(1)` it's inferred that T is `1`. It won't use the default of `string`, even though there was no explicit `match<1>(1)`. So in these particular cases, the default doesn't end up being that important.

Comment: Could you provide an example in which the default does end up being important?